# Multiline not displaying and cmd command won't execute

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying for hours on end now to fix this but I can't. I am working on a project to make a GUI for MaxCSO. So far I have succeeded but now I am stuck. *First I can't get multiline + scroll bar working for the input box(scroll bar doesn't work and the text box only shows the last file selected on the list)*(Fixed) *and second I can't get the command prompt command to execute*(almost fixed but now I need a way to be able to save a file in an *openFileDialog[like a save as window])*(Fixed) and selecting multiple files causes MaxCSO to throw the error too few outputs(I believe it can be fixed by adding -o before each output string but I have no clue how to make it do that.

Here is my code:

```
namespace MaxCSO
{
    public partial class MaxCSOGUI : Form
    {
        //Used to update the text box to the selected input file from openFileDialog
        public string ISOinputFolder
        {
            get { return ISOin.Text; }
            set { ISOin.Text = value; }
        }

        //Used to update the output text box to the selected output dest. in openFileDialog
        string CSOoutputFolder;

        private void OutBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //User selected output path
            SaveFileDialog Output = new SaveFileDialog();
            //Output.Multiselect = true;
            Output.Title = "Set location to save the CSO/s...";
            Output.Filter = "Compressed Disk Image Files(.cso)|*.cso";
            DialogResult dr = Output.ShowDialog();
            //Sets the default output folder to the same as the input if no output is selected
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK || dr == DialogResult.Yes) {
                CSOoutputFolder = Output.FileNames + "\\";
            }else{
                CSOoutputFolder = ISOinputFolder;
            }
                CSOout.Text = CSOoutputFolder;
        }
        //Input Browse button
        private void InBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog Input = new OpenFileDialog();
            Input.Multiselect = true;
            Input.Title = "Select ISO/s to convert...";
            Input.Filter = "Disk Image Files(.iso)|*.iso";
            DialogResult dr = Input.ShowDialog();

            if (dr == DialogResult.OK || dr == DialogResult.Yes)

                //Outputs all selected .iso files to convert
                ISOin.Text = string.Format("{0}", string.Join(" ", Input.FileNames));
        }

        //Confirm button
        private void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Makes sure neither text box is empty before the program continues(program still tries to launch so this isn't working)
            if ((ISOin != null) && (CSOout != null)) {
                compressISO();
            }
        }

        //Cancel Button
        public void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Used to show cancel confirmation box
            ConfirmClose frm2 = new ConfirmClose();
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }


        //Supposed to launch a CMD that executes a command that begins compressing the selected iso files
        private void compressISO()
        {
            string Compress;
            Compress = "/K maxcso64.exe --use-zopfli " + ISOin.Text + " " + "-o " + CSOout.Text + ".cso";
            Process.Start("CMD.exe", Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I just copy pasted the whole file just in case I missed something that is wrong that could be pointed out as I am a total noob)

**Update:** Is there a way to set the cmd to open to a specific path(such as C:\Program Files) before it execute the command and is there a way to set -o before every line in the output textbox(e.g **-o** C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\File1.cso **-o** C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\File2.cso

Comment: You could at least explain which variable is which, show exact inputs and outputs etc. How does "scroll bar not work"?

Comment: Hopefully my edit cleared somethings up, I'm not very good at explaining things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see a lot of problems, but the one you are experiencing right now is caused by the missing parameters for `cmd.exe` to keep your console window open.

Just change the command line to

```
private void compressISO() 
{
     string Compress;
     Compress = "/K maxcso.exe --use-zopfli " + ISOin.Text + " " + "-o " + CSOout.Text + ".cso";
     Process.Start("CMD.exe", Compress);
}
```

then probably you will get other errors, but at least you can see them and report them. After fixing the errors, you could change the `/K` to `/C` if you don't want to keep the console window open after the `maxcso` program terminates its work

[See CMD.EXE Command Shell](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: The problem wasn't that the window wasn't staying open, it doesn't even try to execute the command.

Comment: If you can see the output window then you could see some kind of error message there. Are you sure the command maxcso is in the current path of execution?

Comment: Also you could check if everything works till the execution of maxcso changing (just for debugging) the command line to "/K dir" and see if you could see the content of the current directory (the one where your program executes), after that open yourself a command window, go to that directory and check if manually writing the command maxcso with some valid parameters works or not

Comment: I.... am.... a.... dumbass. I forgot to put it there for testing but how i would like the final product to be is it auto sets the directory to where maxcso is installed(i am also gonna build an installer) then executes the command, which I am still trying to figure out. Also now I get the error could not open output file

Comment: Okay so I just fixed the last problem there I need to change from a file browser to an openFileDialog and go about it that way because there isn't a way to set a name for the output file.

Comment: Also this line doesn't work as you expect: _ISOin.Text = string.Format("{0}", Input.FileNames);_ you need to change it to _ISOin.Text = string.Format("{0}", string.Join(" ", Input.FileNames));_ to allow a multiple selection to be passed as argument

Comment: Thank you, it is now almost 100% fixed. I updated the OP with the current problems and what is fixed.